# Converting DataTable to json with group by using Linq c#

Tags: c#, json, linq, datatable

I want to convert a datatable to json after grouping the data based on specific column .which returns data as follows .

[image]

I need to get the response as

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Car": [
          "Car1",
          "Car2",
          "Car3"
         ],
 },
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Nick"
}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it...

```
 var result = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         group row by row.Field<int>("Id") into Group
                         let row = Group.First()
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = Group.Key,
                             Name= row.Field<string>("Name"),
                             Car = Group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Car"))
                         };
```

Comment: It appears that `Id` in the final result should be sequential and not the grouping key. That's easy though, use the overload of `Select` that takes a lambda with two arguments and use the second one (the index) - - though you'll need the method form and not the query form which does complicate things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> NullIfEmpty(IEnumerable<string> inp)
{
    return inp.Any() ? inp : null;
}

var result = myTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Id = (int) r["Id"],
        Name = (string) r["Name"],
        Car = r.IsNull("car") ? null : (string) r["Car"]
    }).GroupBy(o => o.Name)
    .Select((g, i) => new
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = g.Key,
        Car = NullIfEmpty(g.Select(x => x.Car).Where(x => x != null))
    })
    .ToList();


return Json(result); //if we use asp.net mvc
```

Comment: `Select` has an overload with a lambda taking two parameters, the second of which is the index. There is absolutely zero need for the variable `i`. Side effects in linq methods should be avoided

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:
myTry is the datatable

```
int i = 0;
var test = myTry.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new { Id = ++i, Name = x.Key, 
           Car = x.Where(y=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Car)).Select(y => y.Car).ToList() }).ToList();
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

Comment: `Select` has an overload accepting a lambda with two parameters, the second being the index. No need for the variable `i` or the closure it creates. It's typically a bad idea to introduce side effects such as that with linq methods. Also considering it's a datatable you are missing the meat of the request which would translate `DataRow`s into the expected format